# Scrolling issue on route change

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a store component with a list of products `https://localhost:4200/shop` and a component with product details `https://localhost:4200/shop/10` (opens when you click on a specific product in the store component).
So, why if I scroll down the page of the store component, does the page with details open with a downward scroll after clicking on a product?

Comment: it is because of scroll position in router module. Check documentation about `scrollPositionRestoration` of RouterModule. I had similar issue and find a way with playing `scrollPositionRestoration` options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app routing module, use scrollPositionRestoration like this

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
  })
```

Reference: [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/InMemoryScrollingOptions)